# Laravel POST route returns HTTP code 200 but no record is created

Tags: php, laravel, rest, routes

I have created an Laravel API endpoint `api/post/offer` where it would create a post.
Using a post request from postman.
[postman post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOVHr.png)

Then it will access the route at api.php

```php
Route::post('post/offer', [PostController::class, 'create_offer_post'])->name('create_offer_post');
```

Using the `create_offer_post` method in my PostController

```php
public function create_offer_post(Request $request) {

        //validate data
        $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:50'],
            'postIdentity' => ['required', 'max:100'],
            'postStatus' => ['required', 'max:50'],
            'deliveryArea' => ['required', 'max:500'],
            'shoppingPlace' => ['required', 'max:2000'],
            'deliverySchedule' => ['required', 'date'],
            'transportMode' => ['required', 'max:200'],
            'capacity' => ['required', 'max:100'],
            'paymentMethod' => ['required', 'max:200'],
            'caption' => ['required', 'max:200'],
            'isLoggedIn' => ['required', 'boolean']
        ]);

        dd($request->all());

        // if logged in create offer post
        if($request->isLoggedIn) {
            DB::transaction(function () {

                $post = new Post;
                $post->email = $request->email;
                $post->postIdentity = $request->postIdentity;
                $post->postStatus = $request->postStatus;
                $post->save();

                $offer_post = new OfferPost;
                $offer_post->postStatus = $request->postStatus;
                $offer_post->deliveryArea = $request->deliveryArea;
                $offer_post->shoppingPlace = $request->shoppingPlace;
                $offer_post->deliverySchedule = $request->deliverySchedule;
                $offer_post->transportMode = $request->transportMode;
                $offer_post->capacity = $request->capacity;
                $offer_post->paymentMethod = $request->paymentMethod;
                $offer_post->caption = $offer_post->caption;
                $post->offer_post()->save($offer_post);
            });

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Offer post successfully created.'], 201);
        }
        else {

            return response->json(['error' => 'You are not logged in.'], 401);
        }
    }
```

It validates the request. Then it should save the post in the database.
My problem is whenever I sent the request in postman. It sends a 200 response code. I am expecting a 201 or 401 response code. But I receive a 200 response code and no new record is saved in the database. `dd()` is not working either

Comment: Might be you have missed some attributes which you have used in your Model, Match attributes instead of this you can also use, Resourceful API Patterns

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 0):

You have started the DB transaction but you did not commit it to save the data in database . Maybe the reason behind the error in this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my validation code is not working and returns 200. For the meantime I removed the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using raw instead of form-data in postman.

Comment: It was my request that was malformed. Also I need to set Accept header = application/json.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check for missing parameters[required] in your form data. Thats why the data is not created in your database

Answer (score 0):

```
dd($request->all());
```

This line dumps data and exits. The next lines of your code won't run.